# MongoDB Stitch in Angular 7 application

Tags: angular, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I am trying to add connectivity to MongoDB Stich in my Angular 7 application but app fails with error:

> bson.browser.esm.js:453 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

I am using Angular 7.2.12 and have installed mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk v 4.3.2

I am using the code found on MongoDB website under DB Stitch application client setup.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Stitch, RemoteMongoClient, AnonymousCredential} from 'mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-alfabetisk',
  templateUrl: './alfabetisk.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./alfabetisk.component.css']
})
export class AlfabetiskComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const client = Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('app-id');
  }
}
```

The app fails in ngOnInit() with the error:

> bson.browser.esm.js:453 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
>       at Module../node_modules/bson/dist/bson.browser.esm.js (bson.browser.esm.js:453)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../node_modules/mongodb-stitch-core-sdk/dist/esm/index.js (index.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../node_modules/mongodb-stitch-browser-core/dist/esm/index.js (index.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../node_modules/mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk/dist/esm/index.js (index.js:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)
>       at Module../src/app/alfabetisk/alfabetisk.component.ts (main.js:95)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:78)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to polyfills.ts for Angular 6+

```
/** Add global to window */
(window as any).global = window;
```